# SCSS mixin or function to differentiate between color or gradient

Tags: css, sass

Using SCSS, I want to create a mixin, which will receive parameter and can determine whether it color or gradient and according to it create `background` property.

As possible parameters input:

- any colors values (#hex, rgba, color...).
- any colors SCSS functions (`rgba(color, 0.1)`, `darken(color, 15%)` ...)  as color.
- gradient string ("top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%")

**Pseudo-code:**

```
if color or SCSS color function 
  then background: color;
if gradient 
  then background: -webkit-linear-gradient(gradient);
       background: linear-gradient(gradient);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(gradient);
```

I don't want to use Compass or any other SASS library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** I don't recommend using Sass or Less mixins for performing vendor prefixing. More so for gradients because the old gradient syntax and the new ones are not the same. It is better to leave these sort of things to small libraries like prefix-free or Auto-prefixer etc.

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to differentiate between a color (or color function outputs) and a string [using the `type_of` function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#type_of-instance_method).

Below is a snippet which does what you need. I haven't added any explanation because I feel it is self explanatory. If you find any part of the code to be complex, leave me a comment and I'll explain more.

```
@mixin bg($value){
  @if type_of($value) == 'color' {
    background: $value;
  }
  @else if type_of($value) == 'string' {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#{$value});
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#{$value});
    background: linear-gradient(#{$value});
  }
  @else {
    @error "Invalid parameter. Mixin expects a color or color function or gradient as value. ";
  }
}

#demo.color {
  @include bg(red);
}
#demo.gradient {
  @include bg('top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%');
}
#demo.color-rgba {
  @include bg(rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.1));
}
#demo.color-rgba-sass {
  @include bg(rgba(red, 0.1));
}
#demo.color-hex {
  @include bg(#0f0);
}
#demo.color-function {
  @include bg(darken(red, 15%));
}
/* #demo.invalid-value { if this is uncommented, you'd get the error
  @include bg(1);
}*/
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/YWNJgy) (*click the "View Compiled" button on CSS tab to see output*)

Comment: You're welcome @D.F. Please consider marking it as accepted (click the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons). That is the way to mark a problem as "solved" in Stack Overflow.

Comment: my additional question (if I may), does "if type_of($value) =='color" will be true in case of darken(red, 15%)? will it see it as a color?

Comment: Yes @D.F. It will be seen as a color by the compiler. You can see that in the demo that I'd linked at the end :)